# Gathering data from website value

Tags: vb.net

I got a code I made but it isn't working. I'm trying to make my ListBox1 display data from my website. The value is "boxL" But my code isn't working. Any help please?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("boxL") = ListBox1.Text

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Submit" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

VERSION: VB2013

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "*my code isn't working*"??